# Manually making a Container View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know Container views are just a class of Views. I want to make a container view that is scrollable, so I don't want to be anchored by the default size that the new view controller is forced as.
I wanted to instantiate a ViewController (of its own class) and set it up in the View I already have in my storyboard (instead of programmatically making a rectangle and stuff). The biggest reason for this is that I want to have some delegates to pass information between the main view and the sub-view

```
    class HomeVC: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var subView: UIView! //This one is linked to the Storyboard
        func subViewInit() {
            let resultsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "resultsView") as! GoalsVC
            resultsVC.goalDelegate = self
            // NOW HOW DO I INSERT THIS INTO MY SUBVIEW??
        }
}
```

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach and overcomplicating this?

Comment: It's  unclear what you're asking. You can't insert a view controller into a view. You can only insert views into other views.  Also, you can set up the delegate in Interface Builder if you want to.